# R ggplot reversing one axis of a plot when there is more than one plot in the graph without affecting other plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have plotted a rainfall dataset using ggplot2. I have to plot Rainfall and Stream fall data in the same graph which I have done using this

```
p <- ggplot(data=raw_data, aes(x=Hr, y=RF)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") 

p <- p + geom_line(aes(x= Hr, y=SF))
```

My question is how to make the bar graph upside down. I have already tried using `ylim(60,0)` and `scale_y_reverse` which makes both graphs go upside down. Any help.

Comment: In the one you want to go down, set `y = -SF`.

Comment: Do you mean you want the bar graph to fill downwards from some arbitrary high value towards the actual value? Or, as @gregor's comment, you want it to hang from zero downward to it's negative value? I'm assuming all values are positive here?

Comment: @geryan all values are positive. i want to fill the graph downwards in the same y axis.

Comment: You can't do it elegantly - it's non-standard. You could try creating a dummy data set of equal y values for each x value, then plot them, then plot the real values over the top in the same colour as the background. Should be workable with some tweaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
require(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(3,4))
dfdummy <- data.frame(xx=c(1,2), yy=c(5,5))

 # here the arbitrary hang height is 5, see yy.

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data=dfdummy, aes(x=xx, y=yy), stat="identity") + # dummy bars
  geom_bar(data=df1, aes(x=x, y=y), stat="identity", fill="white") + # overwriting dummy
  theme_classic() # theme w/o grid lines and background matching fill means invisible data
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)